How do I get rebar3 to show runtime errors during boot?
I have an erlang application, which I've recently starting building use rebar3.  Since doing so, any runtime errors which get thrown while the application is booting (eg the address for the server is already in use) get hidden.  What's the easiest way to get these unhandled errors output to stderr?
Previous Behaviour
I'd compile the application with erlc *.erl and run with erl -noshell -run server start.  Errors would get output like:
{error,{badmatch,{error,eaddrinuse}},[{server,start,0,[{file,"server.erl"},{line,11}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}
Runtime terminating during boot ({{badmatch,{error,eaddrinuse}},[{server,start,0,[{file,"server.erl"},{line,11}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Note the very easy-to-spot eaddrinuse.
Current Behaviour
I compile the application with rebar3 compile and run it with bin/prod foreground.  And the output looks like:
Exec: /web/erts-15.0/bin/erlexec -noinput +Bd -boot /web/releases/1.0.0/start -mode embedded -boot_var SYSTEM_LIB_DIR /web/lib -config /web/releases/1.0.0/sys.config -args_file /web/releases/1.0.0/vm.args -- foreground
Root: /web
/web
Runtime terminating during boot (terminating)

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Note that its very hard to determine what went wrong from this output.
If relevant, my rebase.config looks like:
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps,[
  %% Packages
  {gen_smtp, "1.2.0"},
  {jiffy, "1.1.1"}
]}.

{shell, [
  % {config, "config/sys.config"},
    {apps, [lucos_monitoring]}
]}.

{relx, [{
  release,
  {prod, "1.0.0"},
  [lucos_monitoring,jiffy,gen_smtp,sasl,eunit,inets]
}]}.

{profiles, [
    {prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                    {include_erts, true},
                {include_src, false}]}
     ]}
]}.

(I'm also running inside a docker container in both instances, but I don't think that's relevant to the difference in behaviour I'm seeing)
Things I've tried

Setting environment variables ERL_CRASH_DUMP=/dev/stderr andERL_CRASH_DUMP_BYTES=8192 - resulted in lots of info being output, but I still couldn't find eaddrinuse amongst all the noise
Setting environment variable DEBUG=1 - didn't seem to have any impact on the output in this case
Setting {dev_mode, true} in rebase.config - resulted in error Runtime terminating during boot ({load_failed,[heart,supervisor,lists,logger_simple_h,logger_config,logger_backend,logger_server,logger_filters,logger,kernel,gen_server,gen,file_server,file_io_server,filename,file,proc_lib,ets,error_logger,erl_parse,erl_lint,erl_eval,code,application_master,error_handler,application_controller,application,gen_event,code_server]})
Adding {debug_info, keep} to rebase.config  - didn't seem to have any impact on the output in this case


This isn't a rebar3 or relx issue, it's a problem with your code not accommodating all of the possible return values of whatever your server:start/0 calls.
Let's say your application is built around a gen_server that gets started by your server:start/0 function. That's generally done by calling gen_server:start_link(...), which in turn causes your GenServerModule:init/1 callback to be invoked. That function's return value is what's being returned to you at line 11 of server.erl, and the badmatch exception is raised because you're assigning the result directly to a pattern, like {ok, Pid} = gen_server:start_link(...) instead of matching the result in, most commonly, a case statement, as in:
case gen_server:start_link(...) of
    {ok, Pid} ->
        % good, you can continue running
    {error, Reason} ->
        % can't continue - log the error and quit gracefully
end

If you post the relevant section of your code around server.erl:11 it should be pretty easy to troubleshoot.
An unhandled badmatch will always take down the process it occurs in. The VM really doesn't know anything other than that the process terminated abnormally, so that's what gets dumped.
Handle the eaddressinuse error yourself and you can print or log it in a readable format, then shut down cleanly.

Sorry, how are you figuring all that out based on the rebar3 output?
Using the previous behaviour's output, I can clearly see there's an unhandled eaddrinuse error at server.erl:11, and from there it's easy to go fix it.  That wasn't my question.
Now my app is using rebar, I don't understand how to figure out what the error is I need to fix.  My question is how to output the error in rebar3.
